# Error while generating build from jenkins

Tags: android, maven, jenkins

Recently have migrated our Jenkins slave to java 11. After updating to java 11 facing the following errors

```
 1. Certificate for <maven.pkg.github.com> doesn't match any of the
    subject alternative names: [*.registry.github.com,
    registry.github.com]  
 2. org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException(no error message)
 3. peer not authenticated
```

Configuration

```
Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.1+13)
OS:           Linux 4.9.32-15.41.amzn1.x86_64 amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading your local Java version( 11 to 17 etc)

[Similar issue posted here](https://github.community/t/github-package-registry-certificate-mismatch-for-gradle/174732/5)